# How can I remove temp variable aa in the Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A can be compiled, I hope to remove temp variable `aa`, how can I do?

**Code A**

```
    var aa = HomeUIState()

    val homeUIState: StateFlow<HomeUIState> =  combine(
        _audioRecordState, _listSortBy
    )
    { audioRecordState, listSortBy ->

        val eResultMInfo = handelMInfo
            .listAll(listSortBy)
            .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), EResult.LOADING)

        viewModelScope.launch {
            eResultMInfo.map {
                when (it) {
                    is EResult.LOADING -> {
                        log("Load")
                        aa = HomeUIState(audioRecordState, listSortBy)
                    }

                    is EResult.SUCCESS -> {
                        log("Success" + it.data.size)
                        aa = HomeUIState(audioRecordState, listSortBy, it.data)
                    }

                    is EResult.ERROR -> {
                        log("Error")
                        aa = HomeUIState(audioRecordState, listSortBy)
                    }
                }
            }.last()
        }
        aa

    }
        .stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(),
            HomeUIState(audioRecordState = ERecordState.STOPPED)
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe

```
    var aa= HomeUIState(audioRecordState, listSortBy)   // I have to use a temp variable aa, it's ugly
            
     eResultMInfo.map {
        when (it) {
            is EResult.LOADING -> aa=HomeUIState(audioRecordState, listSortBy)
            is EResult.SUCCESS -> aa=HomeUIState(audioRecordState, listSortBy, it.data)
            is EResult.ERROR -> aa=HomeUIState(audioRecordState, listSortBy)
        }
    }
    
    aa
```

is identical to

```
     eResultMInfo.map {
        when (it) {
            is EResult.LOADING -> HomeUIState(audioRecordState, listSortBy)
            is EResult.SUCCESS -> HomeUIState(audioRecordState, listSortBy, it.data)
            is EResult.ERROR -> HomeUIState(audioRecordState, listSortBy)
        }
    }.last()
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I should to add `last` to launch Flow collect, but I always get a `val homeUIState` with  initial value, why ?

Comment: It seems that `HomeUIState(audioRecordState, listSortBy, it.data)` is not always passed to `val homeUIState`

Comment: @HelloCW maybe the EResult.SUCCESS isn't always last in the list

Comment: It's last, I have tested

Comment: I have no idea then

Comment: and   `homeUIState.listSortBy` is initial value too

Comment: I see  the `last()` function just like block function

Comment: maybe I should wrap `last()` with `viewModelScope.launch {}`

Comment: Would you please see my update code in my question, it can work well, but it's too ugly

Comment: @HelloCW in your updated code that `last()` really has no added value, and you still have the `aa` variable

Comment: Yes, the result is not correct, but `homeUIState.listSortBy` has new value when run